# Async Pipe Not Handling Subscription as Expected in Angular 2 App

Tags: javascript, angular, observable, angular2-observables

I have been successfully using Observables throughout my Angular app. Up until now I've been explicitly subscribing in the component, and then using *ngFor to iterate over an array of records in the view. Now I'd like to simplify things by using Angular's async pipe in the various views - so that will handle subscription and un-subscription. So far this isn't working.

This is what I originally had (where I was subscribing in the component):

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.clientService.getAll(1, this.pagesize)
        .subscribe(resRecordsData => {
            this.records = resRecordsData;
            console.log(this.records);
        },
        responseRecordsError => this.errorMsg = responseRecordsError);
}
```

And then in the view I was doing the following:

```
<tr *ngFor="let record of records.data>
```

By the way, the data structure from the API looks like this (the records I am iterating over are within the "data" array, hence "records.data" in the *ngFor above):

```
{
  "count": 15298,
  "data": [
    {
```

So, to move to using the async pipe, I changed my component ngOnInit call to this, where I'm explicitly declaring this to be an observable, and assigning it to a variable "records":

```
ngOnInit() {
    const records: Observable<any> = this.clientsService.getAll(1, this.pagesize);
    console.log(this.records);
}
```

I also brought the observable import from RxJs into the component, like so:

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
```

And then in the view I added the async pipe, like so:

```
<tr *ngFor="let record of records.data | async">
```

As I mentioned this isn't working. I'm not getting any console errors, I just don't see any data populated to the view. Also, in the console, "records" is an empty array.

By the way, my service "getAll" call looks like this:

```
getAll(page, pagesize) {
    return this.http.get
    (`https://api.someurl.com/${this.ver}/clients?apikey=${this.key}&page=${page}&pagesize=${pagesize}`)
        .map((response: Response) => response.json())
        .catch(this.errorHandler);
}
    errorHandler(error: Response) {
    console.error(error);
    return Observable.throw(error.json().error || 'Server error');
}
```

I'm not sure what else is necessary to get the results to populate via subscription through the async pipe here. Any ideas what's missing or in error with my code here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
records$: Observable<any>;

ngOnInit() {
  this.records$ = this.clientService.getAll(1, this.pagesize);
}
```

in the view (assuming you are using Angular 4+):

```
<table *ngIf="records$ | async as records">
  <tr *ngFor="let record of records.data">
```

Comment: Error: inline template:27:24 caused by: Cannot read property 'data' of null

Comment: @Muirik how about `<tr *ngFor="let record of (records$ | async)?.data">`

Comment: Sorry about that Muirik. I updated my answer with an Angular4+ solution. If you're using Angular 2.x then you can use what echonax said.

Comment: A combination of the two answers helped us get to the final solution. Thanks to both of you.

Answer (score 4):

`const records` is a local variable. You need to make it a field in order for template to have access to this variable.

Ex:

```
public records: any;
ngOnInit() {
    this.records = this.clientsService.getAll(1, this.pagesize);
    console.log(this.records);
}
```

Comment: Tried this, but am getting several errors:
1.) ";" expected where ":" is after "this.records"
2.) "Cannot find name 'any'"
3.) And where the "=" is, I'm getting "expression expected"

Comment: @Muirik such as?

Comment: These errors are all showing up in my IDE - Visual Studio Code.

Comment: It doesn't seem to want to let me declare "this.records" here.

Comment: Listed them in my comment above.

Comment: ERROR in /client.component.ts (58,21): ';' expected.

ERROR in /client.component.ts (58,39): Expression expected.

ERROR in /client.component.ts (58,34): Cannot find name 'any'.

Comment: Okay, will try.

Comment: That compiles. But still no data in the view. And I don't see the result of the console.log in the console - just this:
Observable {_isScalar: false, source: Observable, operator: CatchOperator}

Comment: @Muirik the log is true, because `this.records` is an observable. Not a resolved observable like you subscribe to it. Any errors in the console?

Comment: @Muirik do you see the request being made in your network tab?

Comment: No. No request going out. Which also explains why I get no result from my console.log of "this.records".

Comment: @Muirik can you also share your `getAll` method?

Comment: Boom! Got it. Thanks, @echonax. This worked - with this small adjustment:
<tr *ngFor="let record of (records | async)?.data">

Comment: @Muirik you should accept dbandsta's answer then. That answer gave me the idea to write that comment under the answer